# TinyMCE 6 - Quick Toolbar Plugin - Navigate between buttons in Quick Toolbar (Contextual Toolbar) using Keyboard (left and right arrow keys)

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, keyboard-navigation, tinymce-6

I am using TinyMCE 6 (Classic Editor) Quick Toolbar plugin to display context toolbar on text selection.

When I am trying to navigate between buttons inside the quick toolbar using the left and right arrow keys, the toolbar is getting closed.

Can anyone please tell me how to enable keyboard navigation inside TinyMCE 6 Quick toolbar?

Navigate between buttons using the right and left arrow keys inside the Quick toolbar.